# How to change text in textblock from onclick button event in UE5?

Tags: blueprint, unreal-engine5

I am new to Unreal Engine. Currently I am learning UE5.
I am trying to change text and I had run into problem. And somehow I can't find any information about it.

I simply created user widget, I put a button and a text block. So the question is how can I change text in text block using onclick button event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. It was easier than I thought.
[image]

1. First mark your text as variable. Then literally [Get] it in ur bp.
2. Get a branch [set 'name'] from your text (I my case Head Txt).
3. Then from Set set a branch [SetText] and type ur text.

That's it!
Can't believe I spent so many time trying to find the solution in blueprint videos, but accidently found out how to do this from C++ code.

Comment: You don't need the `Set`-node. You can just `Get` the reference and use `SetText`. Setting a variable with itself is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

#### Additional note to this

For beginners, sometimes `SetText` will not show due to "Context Sensitive" is ticked (by default)
[image]

So you need to uncheck the box and make sure to select correct type of `SetText` with correct target widget type.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for it for a while.